# Wrap panel hiding on vertical screen resize

Tags: xaml

Hey so I have a question that's been driving me mad. Basically I have a xaml element that has a wrap panel and a listbox inside it. The listbox has no problems in resizing but the wrap panel will not resize even when I set the horizontal alignment to stretch.

Has anyone any suggestions on how to fix this as it is really driving me nuts? Thanks very much in advance.

```
 <UserControl x:Class="citeright_word.SearchItemsPanel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"         
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:citeright_word"
         xmlns:iconPacks1="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"

         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="562.5" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>



    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Search:" Margin="5,0,0,0" 
  VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    <WrapPanel  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto"  
  Margin="5,30,5,506.4">
        <Button  Click="refreshItems" Background="#FFF7F7F7" 
  VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <iconPacks1:PackIconMaterial  Kind="Refresh" MaxHeight="12" 
  MaxWidth="12"/>
        </Button>
        <TextBox   x:Name="textBox" controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Search 
 Items" controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" 
 VerticalAlignment="Top" 
 KeyDown="textBox_KeyDown"  />
    </WrapPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Margin="5,63,5,5" 
 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

    </ListBox>
</Grid>
  </UserControl>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label 
        x:Name="label" 
        Grid.Row="0"
        Content="Search:" 
        Margin="5,0,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        FontSize="16" 
        FontWeight="Bold"
        />
    <Grid 
        Margin="5"
        Grid.Row="1"
        >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button  
            Grid.Column="0"
            Click="refreshItems" 
            Background="#FFF7F7F7" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            >
            <iconPacks1:PackIconMaterial 
                Kind="Refresh" 
                MaxHeight="12" 
                MaxWidth="12" />
        </Button>
        <TextBox   
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="2,0,0,0"
            x:Name="textBox" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            KeyDown="textBox_KeyDown"
            controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Search Items" 
            controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" 
            />
    </Grid>
    <ListBox 
        x:Name="listBox" 
        Grid.Row="2"
        Margin="5"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBoxItem>DSG Global Inc (re)</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Law Society of New Brunswick v. Aucoin</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

I made some substitutions for testing because I don't have your icons or your textbox behaviors or the stuff that goes in the listbox.

[image]

I find it deeply incongenial to do XAML layout with margins. I know the designer positions elements that way, but I only use the designer for a visual check on the XAML I write by hand. I find it vastly easier and more powerful to use Grid rows and columns, stackpanels, wrappanels, and the odd UniformGrid. I don't think it's just me: On stack overflow, I've noticed that margin-driven layout correlates very well with folks who are inexperienced with XAML.